# Why does jQuery selector only return one element in frame contained within page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML page that contains three iframes.  One of the iframes
contains numerous table rows with the class "twSimpleTableEventRow0".
However, the following jQuery selector:

```
$(".twSimpleTableEventRow0", window.frames[2].document)
```

is only selecting the first element in the HTML layout.  Why aren't
*all* elements with that class selected?

HTML can be found by navigating to this URL in your browser:

http://www.sonoma.edu/calendar/groups/clubs.html

Comment: Can you post the HTML(CSS if possible), and jQuery on a snippet or jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Done.  See listed URL.

Comment: I think I've answered my own question.  To sum up, the function $() was available, but jQuery variable was not -- indicating jQuery was not in fact loaded into the page.  After manually loading jQuery, the selector listed in my original question returned *all* instances of the element with the listed class.   I'll post a former answer in 1-2 days.

Comment: I always do that. I start writing up an question and in doing so find the answer. Well good for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original posting, I used Google Chrome Version 45.x.  For the URL in question, the function `$` is available, but `jQuery` is not.  So, while certainly jQuery syntax worked, such as

```
$("h1")
```

more elaborate syntax did not, such as the frame-based selector I listed
earlier:

```
$(".twSimpleTableEventRow0", window.frames[2].document)
```

After explicitly loading `jQuery` into the page with these directives
issued from the Google Chrome developer console,

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

the javascript interpreter indicated that `jQuery` was defined and the
frame-based selector worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `.each()` function after the selector:

```
 $(".twSimpleTableEventRow0", window.frames[2].document).each(function() {
    // Your code here
 });
```